# Nodejs: JSOn.stringify is rounding the numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Iam having a very weird problem. After making the call to the creditcard processor (CCBILL) with a payment token , they send back a subscription id .For example
0124058201000005323 should get returned. however what gets back is
124058201000005330. As you can see it has been rounded.
I also released that JSON.stringify(0124058201000005323) = '124058201000005330'

Now the weird thing is that when i use postman the response is not rounded and is as expected. am i not making the correct request

I am using node latest v 20
my function is as follows

```
function chargeCCbill(authToken, sendData){ 

  return fetch(`${ccBillBaseUrl}/transactions/payment-tokens/${sendData.paymentTokenId}`,{
    method:'POST',
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',    
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,       
     
     
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(sendData)
  })
  .then((subData) => subData.json())
  .then((json)=>{

      if(json.subscriptionId !== null && json.declineCode === null && json.approved === true ){
            // the json.subscriptionId is rounded here 
         return {status:'success',subscriptionData:json} 
      
      }       
      else{       
         return {status:'fail',subscriptionData:json}
      }
  })
```

I hope you guys can see what i might be doing wrong

I hope you guys can see what i might be doing wrong.

Also there was a option to add the following header
application/vnd.mcn.transaction-service.api.v.1+json

i dont know if that has any bearing. because i dont add that in postman and still gets the correct result. am i making the wrong call?

Comment: I'm guessing that's larger than the max number js can handle (not at my computer), can you verify? Weird they'd send it as a number instead of a string for this reason.

Comment: this is because `124058201000005323 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` ... as to `when i use postman the response is not rounded` because you're looking at the JSON, not the parsed JSON that `subData.json()` returns

Comment: thank you @Jaronmanda. Is there any way i can access this value without parsing the response..

Comment: If they send back `124058201000005330` _as a number_, then that's invalid JSON, and you should contact them about it. Anything that's larger than the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER has to be sent as a string in order to not lose precision (since JSON does not support bigint). However, CCBill is not exactly a small player: look at the _actual_ JSON you get using your browser dev tools, because I flat out don't believe they're not sending that id as a string.

Comment: Thanks @mike. you are correct. i spent hours trying to figure this out and then realized that they are sending me a number

Comment: curiously, if the JSON being returned actually includes the value like that with leading `0`, an error should be thrown

Comment: @Jaronmanda , no leading zeros . i copied that value from their admin tool

Answer (score 2):

Note: Since the question relates to node.js, there will be/is a better way to do this as [this TC39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-parse-with-source) is available in node.js v21.6.2 (maybe a little earlier, but not in v20.11.1)

As a demonstration: NotE: This may or may not run in Edge/Chrome depending on version, it won't run in firefox, other browsers, who knows

Note 2: you'll have to open the browser console, the console on here doesn't show the BigInt

```js
const digitsToBigInt = (key, val, { source }) =>
    !/^[0-9]+$/.test(source) ||
    (val <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER && val >= Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER)
        ? val
        : BigInt(source);

const json = '{ "value" : 124058201000005323, "v2": 123 }';
console.log(JSON.parse(json, digitsToBigInt));
```

---

There is a decent library called json-bigint

You can do something like

```
import JSONbig from "json-bigint";
const JSONbigString = JSONbig({storeAsString: true});
```

Or, if you're using CommonJS it's just

```
var JSONbigString = require('json-bigint')({ storeAsString: true });
```

Then in your current code

```
.then((subData) => subData.text())
.then(json => JSONbigString(json))
.then((json)=>{
```

Now any numbers that are outside the range of "SAFE" integers will be returned as strings

You could also use `{useNativeBigInt: true}` instead of `{storeAsString: true}` and have the number parsed as a `BigInt`

Example (OK browser example but the code is the same in nodejs)

```html
<script type="module">
  import JSONbig from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/json-bigint@1.0.0/+esm';
  const JSONbigString = JSONbig({storeAsString:true});
  var json = '{ "value" : 124058201000005323, "v2": 123 }';
  console.log(JSONbigString.parse(json));
</script>
```

Comment: Small adjustment, this does work after testing but the `value` you have here is the rounded value, not the original octal of `0124058201000005323`. +1

Comment: @Phix - `0124058201000005323` is NOT an octal for a start, and the OP states in a comment that the malformed JSON does NOT contain leading zeros - because, yes, if it did, then that would be an issue

Comment: @Phix - oh, wait, yes I see what you mean by the rounded value - I copied the wrong value :p edited

Answer (score 0):

This is because of floating point precision having lower resolution in high numbers. The details of how floating point numbers are represented in binary are complex enough that I don't want to get into a full-blown explanation in this answer, but it's a format that has very high resolution around 0, allowing very small numbers to be represented, but its resolution gets lower and lower as the number gets further from 0.

When you attempt to construct a large number `124058201000005323` (side note, it's best not to use leading 0s with number primitives as this can be ambiguously interpreted as meaning the number is in base 8, depending on whether or not the number contains the digits `8` or `9`) it will end up being represented by the closest available "slot" that can be represented by JavaScript. For this particular number, that slot is the number `124058201000005330`.

If you need to represent large integers specifically, you should use the [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) type instead of regular numbers. This changes the way the number is represented to allow for a higher resolution when representing large integers. The shorthand for constructing `BigInt` literals is affixing the number with the letter `n`, e.g. `124058201000005323n`, or you can use the `BigInt` function with a string e.g. `BigInt('124058201000005323')`.

Since you're having this problem when reading JSON, you could either fix it when serialising your data so it uses `BigInt` there, or update the way you parse this JSON. The [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function takes arguments including a "reviver", which allows you to specify a custom transformation to make when parsing a JSON blob. You could, for example, tell it to use the `BigInt` function when parsing these numbers to ensure they don't get modified.

Just be aware that you can't "mix" `BigInt` numbers with regular numbers. There are some more details about this in the MDN documentation I've linked to.

---

Another option that may be available to you, depending on how these values are used, is just using a string instead. If really this is just a unique label, and it never needs to be treated as a number (e.g. have its size compared with another number) then a string will give you all the precision you could ever need.

Comment: It feels like this answer misses the part where the data comes from a third party JSON API response. They only have control over how they parse that JSON.

Comment: using a reviver won't fix the issue, since the reviver gets the Number, not the original string

Comment: Yes i have no control on what i get

Comment: @JaromandaX https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-parse-with-source

Comment: @Bergi - hmmm, not even caniuse mention that :p and it is available in NODE

Comment: Once again, my love of Firefox has let me down, Chrome/Edge/Node all have a very easy fix!